# How to find confidence interval for the mean of a variable between two different factors in SPSS?

Tags: confidence-interval, spss

I have data that outlines tumor sizes in patients and whether or not they are male or female. I would like to find the 95% confidence interval for the difference in mean tumor size between male and female.

I have already calculated the confidence interval for mean tumor size in females and in males, but how to I find the confidence interval for the difference of the mean tumor size in SPSS?

Comment: SPSS has nothing to do with this. Are the sizes roughly normal within each sex?

Comment: @gung Yes they are